# flyway create table migration if already exists

Tags: mysql, flyway, migrate

I have a create table migration, I had to run `flyway repair` and because that table already exists in database I can't perform `flyway migrate` , it fails with

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'TABLE_NAME' already exists
```

error message.

Is there any way to fix it without dropping database ? Since it already was populated with data.

Comment: If you start to use Flyway on an existing populated database, you should start by creating a baseline using the flyway baseline command.

In addition to that, you can look into the skipExecutingMigrations flag that together with cherryPick allow you to update the schema history table with the new migration without running the script and getting the error. https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/skipExecutingMigrations

Comment: hi thank you for your response, its not a part of a baseline since that table was created with flyway, but since I have done `repair` command , I can't execute `migrate` again , since that table already exists. `skipExecutingMigrations` is a teams options, not available in community edition. Do I have other options to make `flyway` think that that migration already ran ?

Comment: Try to do in the future idempotent scripts, like `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...`. Also, if you have write permissions, you can touch the flyway_schema_history table to force Flyway run a script again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating those rules for creating a migration:

1. If creating a new table, always use IF NOT EXISTS (thank to @ShaharT 's advice)

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name(
  --params
);
```

2. When altering a TABLE
   We are declaring a procedure that can handle the 1060 MySQL error (column already exists) and adding ALGORITHM and LOCK arguments.

```sql
delimiter ;;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS alterNoFailure;;
create procedure alterNoFailure ()
begin
    declare continue handler for 1060 begin end;
    ALTER TABLE  table_name 
    ADD COLUMN column_name double DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;
end;;
call alterNoFailure();;
```

*You can specify multiple ALTER queries inside the procedure*